# 3 cables in ceiling box, all with white, black and ground

Tags: electrical, ceiling, ceiling-fan

Confused…. Trying to hook up ceiling fan, that has a ground (green) a white, a black AND a black&white wire.

Tried hooking all whites, all blacks, and grounds… why so many options in ceiling box?

Comment: Can you post some photos?  Please clearly show the wires in the box, how they're connected, and the wires on your new ceiling fan.  Did you take any photos of how things were wired up before you started taking things apart?

Comment: What was up there before? Did you note how it was connected?

Comment: Is there a switch that controlled the light and/or fan from before?  That is one cable.

Comment: Post the picture you took before disconnecting any of the wiring. You did take a picture didn't you?

Comment: The color code distinguishes wires in a cable and does not correspond to the meaning/function of the wire.  Because electrical is not designed to be obvious for novices.  It is designed to make houses affordable. As such it requires a certain level of skill. If you lack the skills, either get them, or get your fingers out of that box.  You certainly should not be "trying things" because obviously you will stop "trying" at the first combination that seems to work.  Trouble is, many of those create a hazardous condition.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box please?

Answer (score 1):

> Tried hooking all whites, all blacks, and grounds

That's quite likely to be wrong.

One common arrangement is that one cable is the incoming power.  One is outgoing power to the next light or fan.  The third is a dropwire to a wall switch.

But it may not be like that in your case.  That's why electricians exist as a profession.  Things aren't designed to make it easy for amateurs.

Answer (score 0):

Why so many options? Because you probably have one cable coming in for the always hot and neutral. Then another cable coming in for an outlet or other device that needs a source so it will be connected to the always hot cable. Then you'll have a cable going to the switch box, more commonly known as a switch loop. This cable will energize the switch and return to the ceiling box a switched hot wire to control the fan. You will need to verity what the wires are. Use a volt meter to test for the always hot. Look at the ceiling wires for a black taped white wire and also look in the switch box for a black taped white. That will be your switch cable. Check other rooms to see if some outlets or lights are not working. That would be the extra source that you disconnected. Let us know what you find out and we'll tell you what to do next.